# Generalising JSON response as function parameter

Tags: ios, swift, json-serialization

**JSON Serialization :**

```
var responseDict: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil
    if let anEncoding = responseString?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)) {
    responseDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: anEncoding, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : Any]
}
```

I am passing this responseDict in this function :

```
func apiClientDidFinishWithResponse(response: [AnyHashable : Any]? {

}
```

Now just realised that **responseDict** can be an array as well. What should I keep **responseDict** as ? `Any`, `[AnyHashable : Any]`, `[[AnyHashable : Any]]` ?

Comment: just use `Any?` and inside the function try optional unwrapping as? [Any] & [AnyHashable : Any]

Comment: Unrelated but `String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)` is horrible. You can replace it just with `.utf8`. And `mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift.

Comment: @RatulSharker : Let me check. Hope that gets converted into dictionaries and arrays

Comment: @vadian : Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code, you can see all applications you may  meet when use json.

```
   var responseDict: Any? = nil
    let responseString : String? = "[\"For\", \"BW\", \"Fit\"]"
    if let anEncoding = responseString?.data(using: .utf8) {
        responseDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: anEncoding, options: .mutableContainers) as? Any
    }
   apiClientDidFinishWithResponse(response: responseDict)


  func apiClientDidFinishWithResponse(response: Any?)   {

    switch  response {
    case is [String: Any]:
        print (response) ; //"{\"F\":1, \"B\":12, \"Fi\":11}"
    case is [[String: Any]]:
        print (response); // "[{\"Fd\":1}, {\"BM\":12}, {\"Fi\":11}]"
    case is [Any]:
        print (response) //  "[\"For\", \"BW\", \"Fit\"]"

    default : break;
 }

}
```